# Specify x and y in different coordinate systems in pgfplots similar to gnuplot

Tags: pgfplots, coordinates

In gnuplot you can specify positions in several coordinate systems:
`First, Second, Graph, Screen, Character`.

What are the equivalents in pgfplots?
I know the following:

- `First` : `axis cs:`
- `Second` : `axis cs:` (manual suggests using two axis on top of each other)
- `Graph` : `rel axis cs:`
- `Screen` : can be done with the help of `barycentric cs:`
  `\begin{axis}[name=s]`
  `\end{axis}`
  `\coordinate (topright) at (s.outer north east);`
  `\coordinate (bottomleft) at (s.outer south west);`
  `\node at (barycentric cs:bottomleft=0.5,topright=0.5) {CENTER};`
  (possibly not the most convenient way and only available outside of `\begin{axis}\end{axis}`)

How can one give x and y coordinate in different systems?

Example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.01    1.00
0.02    2.00
0.03    3.00
0.04    4.00
0.05    5.00
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=6]
\addplot table  {\datatable};
\node at (axis cs:0.02,3) {A};
\node at (rel axis cs:0.66,0.5){B};
% \node at (rel axis cs:0.66, axis cs:1){C}; % HOW CAN I DO THIS?
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

I figured out that there are many ways to specify coordinates using

- different coordinate systems (**default** (i.e. without specifying): `axis description cs`),
- predefined nodes,
- predefined anchors, or
- computed values.

Example using the predefined node `current axis`:

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\coordinate (topleft) at ($(current axis.north west) + (-1.3cm,0.3cm)$);
```

These are described in following chapters of the [`pgfplots`](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) manual:

- **4.9.1 Placement of Axis Descriptions**
  coordinate systems: `axis description cs`, `ticklabel cs`
- **4.9.2 Alignment of Axis Descriptions**
  anchors `near ticklabel`, `near ticklabel opposite`
- **4.14.2 Accessing Computed Limit Ranges**
  `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}`
  `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}`
  `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}`
  `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}`
  `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}`
  `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}`
- **4.17.1 Accessing Axis Coordinates in Graphical Elements**
  coordinate systems `axis cs`, `axis direction cs` and `rel axis cs`
  nodes `current plot begin` `current plot end`
- **4.17.2 Placing Nodes on Coordinates of a Plot**
  `\tikz\pos={<fraction>}`
- **4.19 Alignment Options** (!)
  node `current axis` with
  anchors **`center`**, `outer center`, `outer north west`, `north west`, `left of north west`, **`origin`**, `left of origin`, ...
- **4.20 The Picture’s Size: Bounding Box and Clipping**
  `\pgfresetboundingbox`, `trim`
- **4.24 Transforming Coordinate Systems**
  coordinate system `data cs`
- **5.7 Grouping plots**
  anchor `c<x>r<x>.center/left/right`

Relevant sections of the [pgf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) manual:

- **17.5.1 Positioning Nodes Using Anchors** - `center, north west, north, north east, east, south east, south, south west, west, base, mid`
- **17.5.2 Basic Placement Options** - `above/below/right/left, 
  above left/right, below left/right`
- **17.5.3 Advanced Placement Options** - `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you can't address components of different coordinate systems. In fact, I don't think it makes too much sense. However, you can use orthogonal identifiers such as

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % For \pgfplotstableread
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\pgfplotstableread{
0.01    1.00
0.02    2.00
0.03    3.00
0.04    4.00
0.05    5.00
}\datatable

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=0, ymax=6]
\addplot table  {\datatable};
\node at (axis cs:0.02,3) {A};
\node at (rel axis cs:0.66,0.5){B};
\node at ({rel axis cs:0.66,0}|-{axis cs:0,1}){C}; %<=== Like this
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]